# Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows:

Tags: magento-1.7

I am importing products. When I try to import, I get lot of errors.

I have fixed everything and file is valid for import.

After submit import button, it shows the  following error:

> Invalid value for Attribute Set column (set does not exists?) in rows: 11, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26

I have tried googling this error message to no avail.

What do I need to set in attribute_set as I am using the default  values right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem today as I was working through the import process.  What fixed it for me was renaming the "attribute_set" column to "_attribute_set".  I noticed the difference when I exported a CSV from the existing product set and was looking through the exported file for any differences between it and my new CSV.

Comment: I found out a couple more details too as I was working with this.  Magento validates all the values in an imported product against what is in it's database.  So if you try to import a product with an attribute set that doesn't exist yet, Magento will fuss.  The two ways around this are to make sure the attribute set you're importing for has been created, or extend the import module such that it creates any nonexistent attributes, attribute sets, etc rather than just labeling the product as invalid.

Comment: Hi Mike.....I found out a import product details which has been related to database product details.I followed your instruction and make more help us. I have some more doubt in magento and magento admin panel.please adive me..